# AdMob vs AdSense publisher policies and other networks' policies

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I want to create a free app where, if you want to reach a specific activity, you need to to click an ad to get you there. (Let's say a user plays my game, it ends, and he needs to click an ad to get to the score page.)

I've looked at the AdMob policies, which say:

> Ads should not be placed on a "dead end" screen. There must be a way to exit a screen without clicking the ad (for example, a "back" or "menu" button). Otherwise, the user should be notified that the home button will exit the application.

Assuming I'm creating a menu button on that screen that takes the user back to the start, is it ok to do so?

Because AdMob is running AdSense which says in its policies:

> You shall not, and shall not authorize or encourage any third party to: (i) directly or indirectly generate queries, Referral Events, or impressions of or clicks on any Ad, Link, Search Result, or Referral Button  (including without limitation by clicking on “play” for any video Ad) through any automated, deceptive, fraudulent or other invalid means, including but not limited to through repeated manual clicks, the use of robots or other automated query tools and/or computer generated search requests, and/or the unauthorized use of other search engine optimization services and/or software;

Does that mean I'm not allowed to do so? (Both policies were created by Google.)

If not, do you know any network that allows it?

Links to policies:

- AdMob: [AdMob publisher policy](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182)
- AdSense: [AdSense publisher policy](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to force a user to click an add, or to incentivize them to do so in any way really. Bottom line is, find a different model for revenue generation, perhaps in-game products?

I really doubt any ad network would allow you to force a user to click on an ad to do anything. This goes against their models entirely. I sympathize with you, but you've really got to come up with a better business plan to make things work...

Comment: but if i'm placing a "menu" button on that page as mentioned at AdMob policies i'm not actually "forcing" him to click the ad, he can go to menu and exit the game if he wants..

Comment: Yes, but you are forcing them to click if they want some functionality of your game. Ads must be entirely driven by the user to decide to click, and have no other incentive.

Comment: well there must be ad network who allows this since I've seen developers on play store with free apps with more than 10,000 installs that use this model.

Comment: If the ad company finds out, they'll pull all revenue from that product, and ban them. Seriously, I can't imagine any ad company being happy with that...

Comment: Do you have any reference for that happening? On what basis would they be able to pull all revenue? Seems to me nadav is adhering to the guidelines to the letter.

Comment: There are ad companies that pay you for your users to complete an action. eg install another app or watch a video (ie search rewarded video, Chartboost if I remember rightly). Things have changed.