# Add a "Support us by clicking on the ads" android application

Tags: android, admob

I am an android developer for some time but i am new into the admob...

I have two questions for that:

Is it correct to put a text in my app that will inform the user that he can support us
by clicking on the adds ? something like "click on the add to support us!" or it is wrong 
for the admob policy and they will close my account.

And another question is that when i go to admob networks i can enable my app to recieve ads from more than admob network ... should i enable them too ?

Thanks

Comment: Requesting/Suggesting users to click on ads is forbidden by all ad providern as far as I know.

Comment: There is a provider where it is allowed, but I can't remember the name :/ If you find one, pls let me know.

Comment: applovin.com - check this <- Apps like Clicker Heroes or Adventure Capitalist use this advertiser and they force the user to watch the videos. I haven't found any information on their site, if it is forbidden or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, You are not allowed to force a user to click an add, or to incentivize them to do so in any way really. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13612737/1626878) for more explanation.

**guidelines for applications**

- Ads should not be placed very close to or underneath buttons or any other object which users may accidentally click while interacting with your application.
- Ads should not be placed in a location that covers up or hides any area that users have interest in viewing during typical interaction. Ads should not be placed in areas where users will randomly click or place their fingers on the screen.
- Ads should not be placed on a "dead end" screen. There must be a way to exit a screen without clicking the ad (for example, a "back" or "menu" button). Otherwise, the user should be notified that the home button will exit the application.

Have a look at [AdMob publisher guidelines and policies](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307237)

Comment: Thanks for the answer so i have an app that the whole screen is a button so the user can press the button anywhere on the screen.. i placed the app above the button on the top of the screen in order to make it clear for the user that the ad is there ... i think im ok :) the app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=maze.cat.prank&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm1hemUuY2F0LnByYW5rIl0. if you want to check the ad out

Comment: @user878813 : ***Maze and Cat Prank***.! I'll surely check this app.

Comment: but adding a text does not mean forcing user! 
I have a free game with simple banner, bottom the screen. and a text above the ad: support us by watching ads. it down not mean as a force at all. user can play game with out forcing to click on ad at all